# curl command to post data from linux - HTTP/1.1 100 continue

Tags: curl

I am facing an issue when running curl POST command from my linux machine.

Error message is as follows -
curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining

I can successfully POST data in other scenarios like splitting the data in the file and doing it mulitiple times.
Complete response I am getting after running the curl command is as below

```
curl -X POST --data @dataCurl -ik -u userid:password -H 'Accept: application/xml' https://IP_ADDRESS:PORT/rest/xxx/xx/
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 26 Mar 2013 14:54:32 GMT
Server: WebSphere Application Server/6.1

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Tue, 26 Mar 2013 14:54:32 GMT
Server: WebSphere Application Server/6.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
$WSEP: 
Content-Language: en-US
Set-Cookie: LtpaToken2=SaVGscL3xKqJoTFymznYPqJKBuPO5HBhrpSTg2c+cpknypCODPb2r3RzJy7bP7kxoIWWUVS3iAlxIr0WLv5bhW1r2a3nW0i26Iblnlm07Xf
Set-Cookie: LtpaToken=azPyTXehorPwNejA+UFxlrs+7yQfxQoQws/tXc97yQ5IWjykBjIejbp/2cVAHP5CCI01PnrK+TgZq3+C3HM8jc6GovZ9ID+TwjnDZHSvCgOjEk7lZRX2Sqyk49gGE5BMAZaTRJOF5mK0UNCELWG57KunZbSmqOis3h1F5phKOm2duQDqvRf3C54HTLrH60ec1YwMwXVUU9mAECgLIJIZC/2+shzjkn+2zAF3kgN5sDDVvFyO1aCnJje0VcdRosbIqGQgB01sBm4RXqXRtI3RbiHL9ThtHWH62xQwvVh9UYEphK/XY1Zk3vclRX2IFmDqNG8nsR7zIyY=; Path=/
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0000EJSJpUPd0JIBOZcOEZ_oyiC:-1; Path=/
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: Close
Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache="set-cookie, set-cookie2"
curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

If I split the data file into smaller chunks I can POST data.Response at that instance is as below

```
curl -X POST --data @SRPart1 -ik -u userid:password -H 'Accept: application/xml' https://IP_ADDRESS:PORT/rest/xxx/xx/


 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Type: application/xml
 Expires: -1
 Content-Language: en-US
 Set-Cookie: 
 LtpaToken2=I+Gw+zcgPZDCpUWhKIfr53IiOulhfU5gH1rLIzQi9jdpSLASBkCirkle4qDRnkk+1teEkcN/bHq+Amv4BKrK+9xNy4B6RdWPH0O9S2vfnAC5RqmuoSCFwqWXzTINoWGYH+TqqL24KvjhXOWQ43E
```

Is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with an work around, this may or may not be useful for someone in future.

I used awk function and for loop to break my input file into several pieces and then ran curl command to solve this issue.

```
awk '
   BEGIN{ fn = "xxx"; n = 1}
   {
   print > fn
   if (match($0,"YYYID")) {
   close (fn)
   n++
   fn = "xxx" n
   }
   }' inputfile

   for j in xxx*
     do
{          
 curl -X POST --data @$j -ik -u userid:password -H 'Accept: applicatin/xml' https://IPADDRESS/rest/XXX/XX/
         } done
```

Comment: Incase if someone comes with a better idea, plz do share it. It will be helpful in future. thanks.

Comment: If you upload such a big chunk of data, `curl` seems to put in the `Expect: HTTP/1.1 100 Continue` header. And then something goes wrong there. I suspect the server you're uploading to doesn't handle multipart form data properly in that case.